# Angular 1.2.9 resetting field and validation after valid submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, reset

I'm having issues trying to get my form to reset without the required fields error messages appearing. On submit, if the form is valid I call the following function.

```
$scope.reset = function() {
  $scope.createUser.$submitted = false;
  $scope.createUser.$dirty = false;
  $scope.createUser.$pristine = true;
  $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  $scope.createUser.$setPristine(true);
}
```

This resets the form but prompts the following messages.

[image]

Ive been looking for a way of reseting the form to prestine without any luck, im not sure if its because of the way I'm adding the has-error class.

```
ng-class="{'has-error': (createUser.name.$dirty || submitted) && createUser.name.$error.required}"
```

I would be grateful for any help with this, I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FyM81HtDaZ3UMJlrVxxE?p=preview) to go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you wanted but does this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTogzfPcsnPJ4FmYpZwS?p=preview) solve your issue?
first of all like Mathew stated you had an issue with the submitted variable, $submitted is not defined anywhere you wanted to use submitted.
and you want to check your form and only if correct then set it as false.

also I would do validations like so

> ng-class="{'has-error': (createUser.name.$dirty &&
>   createUser.name.$invalid &&  submitted)}"

but you dont have to, for the controller:

```
$scope.reset = function() {

        $scope.submitted = true;
        if($scope.createUser.$valid){
          $scope.submitted = false;
          $scope.createUser.$dirty = false;
        $scope.createUser.$pristine = true;
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
        $scope.createUser.$setPristine(true);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're resetting your submitted variable that you're using in has-error. You're resetting $submitted

Answer (score 0):

Edit your reset function:

```
$scope.reset = function() {

    $scope.createUser.$submitted = false;

}
```

you need nothing else.. good luck :)